# magento https + IE8 Alert Problem

Tags: caching, ssl, internet-explorer-8, magento

I am using magento Enterprise edition 1.9, and after custom theming, site is on live. But the problem is when i open the site in IE8, it gave alert like the page is not safe, since the page is loaded with both http/https content.

Sometime before I got something like this for magento CE 1.4 and it was working as far as I remember.

Default code of getCacheKey

```
public function getCacheKey()
{
    return 'CATALOG_NAVIGATION_' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
        . '_' . Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName()
        . '_' . Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template')
        . '_' . Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()
        . '_' . md5($this->getTemplate() . $this->getCurrenCategoryKey());
}
```

is then replaced by following code

```
public function getCacheKey()
{
    return 'CATALOG_NAVIGATION_' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
        . '_' . Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName()
        . '_' . Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template')
        . '_' . Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()
        . '_' . md5($this->getTemplate() . $this->getCurrenCategoryKey())
        **. '_' . md5($this->getSkinUrl());** 
}
```

This is it. You can now use peacefully https on Internet Explorer.

By adding this line skin also comes into https whenever https page is loaded, so I didn't get error that time. But here in EE 1.9 I am not able to find this function
in **Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation**.

I tried with command line,

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "getCacheKey()"
```

This does not return the function in this way, that function having some other cache info.

Is anybody solved this issue. Please help to find this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following code block in `DOCROOT\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Navigation.php`:

```
/**
 * Get Key pieces for caching block content
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $shortCacheId = array(
        'CATALOG_NAVIGATION',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
        'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
        'name' => $this->getNameInLayout()
    );
    $cacheId = $shortCacheId;

    $shortCacheId = array_values($shortCacheId);
    $shortCacheId = implode('|', $shortCacheId);
    $shortCacheId = md5($shortCacheId);

    $cacheId['category_path'] = $this->getCurrenCategoryKey();
    $cacheId['short_cache_id'] = $shortCacheId;

    return $cacheId;
}
```

You should be able to override and update the returned keys to suit your purpose.

Cheers,
JD

Comment: Hi yes, thats the one i think, But i did added this line. 'skin' => $this->getSkinUrl() but still its showing warning on the https pages when its mixed copntent page.